# Find row in array corresponding to combination of numbers

Tags: python

I am working with q-tables and I got 30 * 30 * 30 * 30=810000 different states. I want a function that takes for example [10, 20, 16, 5] as input and this should correspond to a particular row representing this exact combination of state but I cannot figure out how to do that. One (bad) approach would be 10 * 20 * 15 * 5=15000 but then row number 15 000 would also be represented by 20 * 10 * 5 * 15 = 15000 and I do not want that. How can I make this work?

Comment: Why use an array/list, rather than a `dict`, using, for example, the tuple `(10, 20, 16, 5)` as a key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to represent your table as a 4-dimensional list:

```
    self.q_table = [[[[0 for _ in range(30)] for _ in range(30)] for _ in range(30)] for _ in range(30)]
```

so you can do:

```
def func(self, coords):
    [q, r, s, t] = coords
    entry = self.q_table[q][r][s][t]
    ...
```

If you wanted to flatten it to a single-dimensional list, then you need to multiple each coordinate by an increasing power of 30 to make sure each combination of coordinates yields a unique result:

```
    self.q_table = [0 for _ in range(30**4)]

def func(self, coords):
    row_num = sum(i * 30**p for p, i in enumerate(coords))
    entry = self.q_table[row_num]
    ...
```